# MVVM Shared Events

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 3 ViewModels, let s say ViewModelA, ViewModelB and ViewModelC.
Each view Model has a corresponding View.

In ViewModelA I have a Public Event that I`m using send some information.

I want ViewModelB and ViewModelC to subscribe to that Event in the current/Running instance of ViewModelA?

How can I do this?
If a new a ViewModelA I will have a different instance of ViewModelA, so I need a reference to the current ViewModelA...

Note: I`m not using MVVM Light or nay other framework (yet), because I did not learn them, yet :)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating new views from the view of ViewModelA you can pass the reference to another view like this

```
var viewModelA = DataContext as ViewModelA;
var newWindow = new ViewB(viewModelA);
```

Then you would need to have a property in your ViewModelB

```
public ViewModelA MyViewModelA { get; set; }
```

And in your new view:

```
public ViewB(ViewModelA viewModelA)
{
    InitializeComponents();
    var viewModelB = DataContext as ViewModelB;
    viewModelB.MyViewModelA = viewModelA;
}
```

And then you can access your ViewModelA via MyViewModelA.

I've always done it like this and haven't seen any problems so far.

Comment: Thank you but I want to avoid code behind like that, I m using MEF to Import/Export my MainViewModel DataContext, and then I m using ViewModelLocator from WPF DataTemplates to resolve DataContext/Views. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can implement some kind of simple Publisher/subscriber like this one on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/866547/Publisher-Subscriber-pattern-with-Event-Delegate-a). You will be one step ahead because most of frameworks has something similar:

In MVVM light it is called [Messenger](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/NET45/index.html):

In Prism there is [EventAggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx)

2) *Ugly solution would be to create static event in ViewModelA, this way you won't need a reference*

Comment: I end up creating a separated static class to my public events where aother viewmodels could subscribe / publish their events, but I ll try mjay 3rd link suggestion... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

While you can pass references between ViewModels, it makes your app tightly coupled and not particularly scalable.  Also if you decide to make a change in the future the amount of refactoring quickly grows making managing changes a lot more difficult.

Have a look at a PubSub Event framework.  These are all included in MVVM Frameworks such as PRISM or MVVM-Light that you mention, but you can always add your own version if you don't want or need the full frameworks mentioned above.

Have a look [here](http://www.codearsenal.net/2013/07/pub-sub-observer-pattern-in-mvvm.html#.WDGuPYXXI2w) for a simple no nonsense implementation that you should be able to adapt to your own requirements.

Comment: Hum... During this process I end up creating a separated static class to declare the public events and each class can publish subscribe to it, and is working... Bu now seeing the 3rd option from your suggestions, I really like it, I`ll give it a try on that one... Thank you.